# Is Fermat's Little Theorem possible over additive group?

Tags: group-theory

As Fermat's Little Theorem is define over multiplicative group $a^{p-1} \mod p$ = $1 \mod p$. Is there something over additive group?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), which among other things implies that for any group $G$, if $m$ is the order of that group then for every $g \in G$ we have (multiplicative notation) $g^m = 1$ or (additive notation) $mg = 0$. Fermat's little theorem is merely a special case of this result for integers modulo $p$ under multiplication, while the more general Euler's theorem is also a special case of the result for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ for arbitrary $n$ (not just prime).